# Renew SSL certificate in XAMPP for Mac OS

Tags: ssl, web, https, xampp

Recently, the Apache web server of the XAMPP package started to give me an error when accessing with the https protocol (before it also gave me an error, but it let me access indicating that it was not safe. Now I can not access it in any way).

I have seen the certificate of the page and it is the one that came by default from apache, which has expired since 2010 (Before, despite being outdated, it let access). I tried to reinstall it, but it's still the same.

I need to know if there is any other way than to renew the certificate. In case you find that renew the certificate what would be the steps to renew it in XAMPP?

I use the MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4 operating system and the XAMPP version 7.2.3. I do not want the answer for Windows

I am not very expert in the subject, so would like a solution that is as simple as possible.

[Error accessing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMa3c.png)

[Digital certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qszbB.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've also been having this same issue with XAMPP and Mac OSX for about a week now and finally figured it out. It seems that the generated cert that XAMPP sets up is either super expired, or no longer valid in some way with chrome.

What I did to resolve this was backed up the current certs just in case.

And followed this readme https://gist.github.com/nrollr/4daba07c67adcb30693e

I just changed all the paths to my XAMPP ssl location /Applications/XAMPP/etc rather that the default apache location and created the ssl directory for the locahost files it has you create

once everything was setup and installed (I use a vhost) in the httpd-ssl.conf in the "extra" directory changed the ssl cert location to the new ones I created.

`SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/localhost.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ssl/localhost.key"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been able to solve it, it has been very useful for me.